# how to use private keys when working with smart contract

Tags: truffle, ether, wallets, private-key

Here is my scenario .
We have wallets (accounts) with private keys . In case of raw transaction I know how I can use private keys for signing tx  . How I can use private key for an account when I am calling smart contract methods ? 
Thanks

Comment: You want to use the private keys of these wallets in the smart contract?

Comment: Yes , I understand in order to interact with wallets you need to use private keys , but in smart contract I don't see a way

Comment: You don't need the private keys to "interact" with wallets. What do you want to do? Send ETH or tokens?

Comment: yes sending tokens

Comment: You don't need the private key for sending tokens.

Comment: Elisha thanks for response . 
Can u please send me an example usage or a link where I can find how to usage or deep explanation on this ?

Comment: Of course you need private key to send tokens. It's a transaction. I'll write you an example

Comment: you mean , you want to do transasction using smart contract . please specify that you want to send transaction from contract to any other address or using web3js and smart contract(token transafer form one address to another using method specified in contract).

Answer (score -1):

Here are three functions I use a lot to interact with a smart contract and a signed transaction:

```
function sendTransaction(tx) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        web3g.eth.sendSignedTransaction(tx.rawTransaction)
            .on('transactionHash', function (hash) {
                resolve(hash);
            });
    });
}
// tx = the transaction object from "generateTx"
function signTransaction(tx, private_key) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        web3g.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, private_key)
            .then(function (signed_tx) {
                resolve(signed_tx);
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                reject("request failed");
            });
    });
}

// instance = contract instance
// body = some parameters
function generateTx(body, instance) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            let encoded_tx_data = instance.methods.transfer(body.destinationAddress, body.transferAmount).encodeABI();
            let tx_object = {
                gas: 2000000,
                data: encoded_tx_data,
                from: body.senderAddress,
                to: body.contractAddress
            };
            resolve(tx_object);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            reject("request failed");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: but those are jsut methods to interact with web3 right ? you don't have this methods in smart contract ??

Comment: No you don't. Priate keys have nothing to do ith smart contract itself

Comment: in that key s if you have bunch of wallets and private keys  , how do you make transactiopns using sm contract methods

Comment: yes for instance to send tokens using web3